# Docker - where is data of installed application stored?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I have (working with Ubuntu) started Docker daemon with --data--root flag in order to change directory where images and containers are stored (from default directory in root partition to partition residing in another disk). Then I created Dockerfile with MongoDB installation. During building this image over 400MB of data is downloaded and stored in disk. And here is my question: where is this data stored? Docker has created few new folders in directory passed with --data--root, like builder, container, image, swarm etc, but they all weigh 4KiB.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu it is kept in `/var/lib/docker`.

This directory should contain the following dirs.

`drwx------  2 root root 4096 Jan  3 09:06 builder/
drwx--x--x  3 root root 4096 Jan  3 09:06 containerd/
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Jan  3 09:06 containers/
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Jan  3 09:06 image/
drwxr-x---  3 root root 4096 Jan  3 09:06 network/
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Jan  3 09:06 overlay2/
drwx------  4 root root 4096 Jan  3 09:06 plugins/
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Jan  3 09:06 runtimes/
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Jan  3 09:06 swarm/
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Jan  3 09:06 tmp/
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Jan  3 09:06 trust/
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Jan  3 09:06 volumes/`

If you're *not* using the latest version of Docker (17.12 as of writing), you'll have `aufs` instead of `overlay2`, the new default. This is where the docker "layers" of your images and containers are stored. Most of the storage taken should be there unless you store a lot of data in docker volumes (the `volumes` dir).

Comment: Indeed, overlay2 size  did increase after building an image. What bothers me is vast disproportion between size of installed application and of overlay2. I thought that maybe this data is cached, but it still, I assume, has to saved to be available after reboot.